# C function with array pointer

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I'm trying to write a function that when given an array and a value, it checks if the value is in that array. If it is there then keep finding a new unique random value before adding it to the array. This is what I have done so far but I think the problem is my lack of understanding of pointers. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int getNewIndex(int index, int *visitedPixels, int *visitedPixelsIndex);

int main() {

int *visitedPixels = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
int *visitedPixelsIndex = 0;
srand(1);
int randIndex = rand() % 16, i;

printf("Initial randIndex = %d\n", randIndex);

for(i =  0; i < 16; i++) {
    randIndex = getNewIndex(randIndex, visitedPixels, visitedPixelsIndex);  
    printf("randIndex[%d] = %d\n", i, visitedPixels[i]);
}
return 0;
}
int getNewIndex(int index, int *visitedPixels, int *visitedPixelsIndex) {

    int i = 0;
    while (i < *visitedPixelsIndex) {
        (index == visitedPixels[i]) ? index = rand() % 16, i = 0 : i++;

    }

    visitedPixels[*visitedPixelsIndex] = index;
    (*visitedPixelsIndex)++;
    //(*visitedPixels) = realloc(visitedPixels, (*visitedPixelsIndex+1) * sizeof(int));

    return index;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what you want help with. What is not working? What happens and what should happen instead?

Comment: Hi. So the problem is that the visitedPixels and visitedPixelsIndex values are not being updated. From my understanding, the pointer values should remain the same as previous iteration each time the function is called. For example, the in the first iteration, 7 will be added to vistedPixels array. I want that 7 to stay in the array the next time the function is called, instead of it and visitedPixelsIndex being reset.

Comment: Array `visitedPixels[]` only has two elements allocated, but 16 elements are looped through, and the elements are never initialized.  Integer `visitedPixelsIndex` is passed by value to pointer parameter.  You should pass `&visitedPixesIndex`.

Comment: Aside: please note that `srand(1);` will produce the same sequence every time — useful for debugging but is usually better to comment out `//srand(time(NULL));`

Comment: @KenJackson Passing the value by & seems to have fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: One more question though. So if I have allocated the memory by size 2 in the beginning, I want to reallocate the memory each time a new value is added. But when I try to do     visitedPixels = realloc(visitedPixels, (visitedPixelsIndex+1) * sizeof(int));
 it says Invalid operands to binary expression ('int *' and 'unsigned long'). What does that mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: @NaeemKhan Since `visitedPixelsIndex` is a pointer, that code is now incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so. I'm going to try to explain with a metaphor. Hopefully it helps rather than confusing more.

Imagine memory is a long board you can write numbers on. It takes an inch of board to write a small number. Bigger numbers can be represented by writing across more slots.

An array, in our metaphor, is just a contiguous length of board you can write stuff into. If you want an array of 5 integers, and each integer takes 4 inches, you'll need 20 inches of board for it. If you wanted to pass all these integers to a function, instead of copying them all across, you would instead write down how many inches from the end of the board your array is. That's what a pointer is. It's a number telling where something is.

When you called `malloc( 2 * sizeof( int ) )`, you requested for a segment of the board big enough for two integers, and you received how many inches from the end of the board that new segment is. So we've got 8 inches of board X inches from the end, with X being our pointer.

Incrementing a pointer says "increase this value to point at the next element of the underlying array". A `int*` will increase by 4, a pointer to a structure by the size of the structure plus any alignment offset the compiler has decided for it.

It does not increase the amount of storage.

If I have a pointer to two 8 inches of board, write a 4 inch number, increment the pointer to point 4 inches more in, write another 4 inch number and increment again, my pointer is now right after the last element of the array. If I write here, all bets are off. What was on the board after the array? Who knows. It could be anything. Maybe it was a different array. Maybe it was information for keeping track of what parts of the board have been handed out to the program. Maybe it was the end of my board and I'll write off the end. Writing to memory you haven't received permission to from the operating system is where signals for "segment violations", SIGSEGV, program failures come from.

You need to request more space up front, or bigger arrays as you need them. There's also a realloc that will do this too. And for all of them, you have to check if the call failed and terminate or otherwise recover appropriately.

Hopefully this is more helpful than confusing. Good luck :)

Comment: This was very helpful. I just realized a lot of mistakes I have done allocating memory because of this. Thank you!